# javascript to get the latest copy of the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I wrote a function that calls the below code at the specified time for eg call it every day at 4 pm... I have seen the page is being reloaded, just curious whether the latest copy of the webpage update(if any) will be retrieved by calling this function. The webpage is based on asp.net.

If I change something and republish the webpage, will the latest copy of the webpage be retrieved by this line of code, so that users can get the latest copy.

window.location.href = window.location.href;

Comment: this has strictly nothing to do with asp.net... It's also very unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking ctrl+f5 should do a hard refresh.